# How to add extra data in response if Validation fails in FormRequest Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to add custom tag in response if the validation fails in FormRequest.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreMessage extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|max:1000'
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(\Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {

               if($validator->fails()) {
                   $validator->errors()->add('status', 'error');
               }

        });
    }

}
```

If my any of the validation fails only then I need to add `status = error` in json response else I need to add `status = success`.

Also my response status is nested under `errors` tag I need it to be at level 0.

```
    {
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The name may not be greater than 100 characters."
    ],
    "status": [
      "error"
    ]
  }
}
```

Purpose of this is I am sending Ajax request to submit a form i need a flag to identify whether error occurred or not. Is there any better way to do this.
Pardon me if I am asking silly question. I am newbie to laravel.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) (search for "AJAX"):

> When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

In your Javascript, you can catch this happening in [a `.fail()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**UPDATE** Simple example, doesn't handle formatting multiple validation errors but gives you the idea:

```
$.ajax( ... )
.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    if (error === 'Unprocessable Entity') {
        // validation failure
        var msg = '';    
        for (error in xhr.responseJSON) {
            msg += xhr.responseJSON[error];
        };
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: ’t panic thanks mate that helped. On query is it safe to match Unprocessable Entity in if block. Will it always return this or is there is any safest method.

Comment: @Abhishek Good question. I think it is safe, it is the `textual portion of the HTTP status` (quoted from jQuery docs), so it will always match exactly response code 422.  That's what Laravel validation failure returns, and AFAIK it won't return it in any other circumstances.

Comment: this is what I call a perfect response of doubt with proper explanation

Comment: @Abhishek if you are using > 5.2 laravel than use axios instead of ajax call. Axios is more powerful library to work with.

Comment: @RutvijKothari thank you for the suggestion. Axios comes with Vue.js correct me if i am wrong. What you suggest shall i move to Vue.js from jQuery.

Comment: @Abhishek Axios is a different library and independent one. You can use it without using Vue.js. No need to migrate from jQuery to Vuejs, it requires lots of efforts and too much work. I am just suggesting you to use axios instead of jquery.ajax method.

Comment: @RutvijKothari ok will checkout the library once.