# Add Data If Validator Fails in Form Request

Tags: laravel

I've checked the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410162/how-to-add-extra-data-in-response-if-validation-fails-in-formrequest-laravel) but when I do the following I get the error `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`.

In my custom form request I have:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            session()->flash('type', 'xyz');
        }
    });
}
```

As soon as I removed the `if` statement the max execution error goes away.

How can I add some data to session if validation fails?

Answer (score 1):

As said in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests)

> `withValidator` allows you to call any of its methods before the validation rules are actually evaluated

So, you cannot call `fails()` method inside withValidator method. Because it **performs** validation and cannot be called in a method that adds a rule that is ought to perform **before** validation.

You should define a validator as said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook) in your **controller**, then call `fails()` method on it.

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    session()->flash('type', 'xyz');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because what has mentioned in [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests) was:

> call any of its methods **before** the validation rules are actually
> evaluated

your code going through an **infinite loop** by **recursive calling himself** on calling `$validator->fails()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are calling `fail` in the `after` callaback and this is doing an infinite recursive call. Let me explain:
if you dig in the source code here is the `fails` implementation:

```
public function fails()
    {
        return ! $this->passes();
    }
```

Here is our interesting part of the `passes()` method:

```
 public function passes()
    {
       //.....
       //once the validation fails call the callback
        foreach ($this->after as $after) {
            $after();
        }
    
        return $this->messages->isEmpty();
    }
```

So if in the `after()` callback you are calling the `fail()` method then the `fail()` method will call the `after()` callabck etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some data when the validation fails using after validation hook, you can try to check if the error bag has any messages and if it has then flash the requisite data to session

```php
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function($validator) {
            if($validator->errors()->count('messages')) {
                session()->flash('type', 'xyz');
            }
        });
    }
```